# Not getting SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS message for async test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am creating test case to demonstrate angular testing with asynchronous code and I want to get SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS, I have following code :

```
   describe('EmployeeService', () => {
  let service: EmployeeService; 

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [EmployeeService]
  }).compileComponents());

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(EmployeeService);
  });

  it('should be return list of employee names ', () => {

        service.getListOfEmpNames().subscribe((data: string[]) => {

        expect(data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

  });

});
```

and the method in EmployeeService:

```
getListOfEmpNames(): Observable<string[]>{
    return of(['Rohan', 'Ethan', 'Pruthvi']);
  }
```

As per my understand when we are testing asynchronous code without done or async or fakeasync it will pass the test, but will also display message before description - SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS(please correct my understanding if wrong).
Also want to know if there is any configuration that can help to add or suppress such message.

Comment: I suspect the `subscribe` doesn't even fire, and the testcase doesn't know it needs to wait for the result. You should tell the framework it needs to wait for results to be available. Don't suppress the message, you're not testing anything (might as well don't make the test after all).

Comment: subscribe is executed, earlier i had added a  console.log('inside subscribe'); inside subscribe, it got printed on console.

Comment: After or before the test attained it's result?

Comment: before and after both getting printed,

Comment: before and after both getting printed, even expect is getting executed, I changed it to -         expect(data.length).not.toBeGreaterThan(0); it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious like `Caramiriel` where the subscription is not being fired.

Try:

```
it('should be return list of employee names ', async(done) => {
  const data = await service.getListofEmpNames().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  expect(data.length).toBeGreatherThan(0);
  done();
});
```

I usually don't like `subscribes` in my tests because I don't know if it ever got executed. I wait for a promise to complete (then I know it got executed) and in this case if `getListOfEmpNames` never returns anything, the test will be stuck on resolving the promise thereby giving you better "engineering".

Comment: Objective here is to show message spec has no expectation

Comment: But it does, `expect(data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)` is an expectation.